# Can a player be switched mid game in pro LoL game?

Tags: league-of-legends, competitive-gaming

Can a LoL player be switched with a sub mid game?

I was watching a professional match and the game paused, because a player disconnected. Can someone log in using his credentials and continue playing the game legally? For example in online qualifications?

Comment: My instincts say no, but I'd have to take a look at LCS rules to say for sure

Comment: I wondee why I got downvoted. (:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [LCS rules book](https://esports-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/production/files/rules/EU_Rulebook.pdf), you can read under point 3.4 Substitutions:

> 3.4.1 A Team may substitute a Player between Games of a Match. The Team must notify a League Official and have the substitution approved,
>   no later than 5 minutes after the explosion of the Nexus in the
>   previous Game.
>
> 3.4.2 In the event of an emergency, a Team will be given up to two hours to find an immediate Substitute from their Roster for a Game. If
>   a replacement cannot be found, the Team will forfeit. League Officials
>   will determine if an event qualifies as an emergency.
>
> 3.4.3 Player substitutions have to result in Teams having eligible Rosters

To me it sounds like you can swap a player mid game, but only if there is a serious emergency.

I am not quite sure how the game you mentioned continued, but a disconnect can happen due to various reasons like a bluescreen, power-outage and so on.

Comment: I was referring to Kliktech vs. Origen (EU Masters 2018 Spring) that took place last night. A player disconnected and they went back to the commenters, while the issue was resolved. Few minutes later the game continued normally, but since no one could see the faces of the players (like in an offline event), I thought that the player that disconnected might never comeback due to Internet issues/power-outage etc & he could have been replaced.

Comment: Sadly the rules don't give examples for these emergencies, but maybe a power-outage is already considered an emergency and they switched players